# Behavior of API Request with "Keep-Alive" Header when machine is in locked state

Tags: json, api, curl, keep-alive

What exactly is the "Expected Behavior" for API request which had below Headers included in API Request:

> curl -H "Authorization: Token <>" -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" **-H** **"Connection: Keep-Alive"** "https://....." -v

API also returns \r\n" delimiter if there is no matching events for keeping it live.

Should the connection Stay active or any error is possible in such scenario.